# How to know if the value of a checkbox in a tableColumn had change in javafx

Tags: javafx

hi I created a checkbox in tablecolumn:

```html
 col_orien.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Information, Boolean>("orientation"));
  col_orien.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(col_orien));
  col_orien.setEditable(true);

      col_orien.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Information,Boolean>>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(CellEditEvent<Information, Boolean> event) {
         System.out.println("Edit commit");
       }
     });
```

The problem is when I changed the value of the checkbox the message didn’t appear

Comment: Can you show a bit more of how you have set the column up - for example the `cellFactory` and `cellValueFactory`?

Comment: Also post your Information class (or at least the "orientation" property parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadocs for `CheckBoxTableCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html):

> Note that the CheckBoxTableCell renders the CheckBox 'live', meaning
>   that the CheckBox is always interactive and can be directly toggled by
>   the user. This means that it is not necessary that the cell enter its
>   editing state (usually by the user double-clicking on the cell). A
>   side-effect of this is that the usual editing callbacks (such as on
>   edit commit) will not be called. If you want to be notified of
>   changes, it is recommended to directly observe the boolean properties
>   that are manipulated by the CheckBox.

Assuming your table model class `Information` has a property accessor method for the `orientation` property, i.e.

```
public class Information {
    // ...

    public BooleanProperty orientationProperty() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

then the orientation property of the relevant object will be updated automatically when the check box is selected and de-selected. Hence all you need to do is listen for changes on those properties themselves:

```
Information info = new Information(...);
table.getItems().add(info);
info.orientationProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) 
    -> System.out.println("orientation property edited"));
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I populate the tableview with an ObservableList, the table initially isn't empty it contain 4 rows and I want to know if a checkBox in a column is change

Comment: If the check box changes, the corresponding `BooleanProperty` changes. Just observe the properties - think in terms of the underlying data changing instead of thinking about the UI.

Comment: in my case, the first thing that i do is that I fille the table view from the DB, so I cannot do 'Information info = new Information(...);'

Comment: No but you can still add listeners to the properties. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: well, first of all a have to file the table with data, let’s say that I want 4 row, so I have to add them like that :                               Information info = new Information(...);//1st row 
table.getItems().add(info);                                                Information info = new Information(...);//2nd row
table.getItems().add(info);                                                .....

Comment: I'm really confused here. All you have to do is add listener to the `orientationProperty` of each one. That has nothing to do with how you create them. You could just wait until after you've added everything to the table and then do `for (Information info : table.getItems()) { info.orientationProperty().addListener(...); }`

Comment: I understand now, it was my fault. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

i use this solution :

```html
   ObservableList<Information> data =  FXCollections.<Information>observableArrayList( 
           new Callback<Information, Observable[]>() {
             @Override
             public Observable[] call(Information inf) {
               return new Observable[]{inf.orientationProperty(),inf.istProperty()};
             }
           }
       );

      data.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Information>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(
            javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Information> change) {
          System.out.println("List changed");
          while (change.next()) {
            if (change.wasUpdated()) {
              System.out.println("List updated");
              System.out.println(change.getAddedSubList());
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

And it's work, but in my table there is  2 columns with check box(orientation ,ist).how can I know which of the 2 columns had change, when I get the message