# JavaFX TableView how to get a row cell graphic

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX TableView, the first column is a selection checkbox column, user can select the checkbox and do something. And in the header column, it have a checkbox, I wan't it to be select all, when selected this column, it will select all checkbox to be selected. But the question is I haven't found there have any methods or ways in the JavaFX TableView or TableColumn to get the checkbox in the table row. If I can the checkboxs in the table row, I can change their state to checked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should bind the check box state to the state of your model object; then you can just observe or query the tables items. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661745/how-to-know-if-the-value-of-a-checkbox-in-a-tablecolumn-had-change-in-javafx/27668471#27668471

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used you method resolved whether my model is checked problem. But futhurmore I wan't to trigger a button click action the the row, in this case, I still need to get the cell node in the row.

Comment: The check box state is bound bidirectionally to the property. So if you just set the property (which only needs access to the model), the check box should update automatically.